# How to control bounded source split?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I have a Dataflow where the input is a large read from a database. I would like to split this query up and have it executed from multiple hosts when the job starts. As far as I can tell, the `BoundedSource` has no way of directly controlling the input split. The closest it has is `splitIntoBundles` which basically means I have to start a very expensive read and hope Dataflow cancels it and uses my defined bundle split instead. This seems pretty crazy, so I'm hoping there is a better way of predefining an input split that can be run on any remote workers.

Comment: What database are you reading from? Are you querying Big Query? Or did you write a custom source?

Comment: I'm reading from Mongo. I've implemented a custom source.

Comment: Looking at the beam code, it seems that there's a MongoDB source that does implement `splitIntoBundles`. Perhaps you can try exploring this implementation?
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/MongoDbIO.java#L226

Comment: The reason that implementation of `splitIntoBundles` does not work for me is that I want to control the exact number of splits for the entire job. That implementation relies on the desired bundle size and the "estimated" size for a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, there is no way to control the split parallelism of a single reader. My solution was to create multiple readers, have each reader read into its own PCollection, and then flatten the multiple PCollections into a single PCollection.